# Turn-off Google Maps MouseWheel Zoom Ctrl

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've got update with Google.Maps API3 library. Every time I try to zoom-in or zoom-out map it is notification appear that zoom control available with pressed Ctrl/Cmd Button only.
[image: Opac overlay with Ctrl only info]

It is something new and I've no idea how to turn it off as it was before - zoom without additional buttons press.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add `gestureHandling: 'greedy'` to your google.map options during instantiation.

E.g:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {0, 0}, 
        zoom: 8, 
        gestureHandling: 'greedy' 
    });
}
```

Comment: gestureHandling parameter 'greedy' was correct way to resolve it! Thank you!